# Is there a way to do a #define inside of another #define in c?

Tags: objective-c, c

I want to achieve the same as you would in the `stringWithFormat` method.

I was wondering if you could call in another constant inside my `#define`?

e.g. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"If you enjoyed %@ would you mind please reviewing it?", appName];`

I want:

```
#define appName @"This App"

#define myMessage @"If you enjoyed **appName** would you mind please reviewing it?"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define appName     @"This App"
#define myMessage   @"If you enjoyed " appName @" would you mind please reviewing it?"

int main( void )
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSLog( myMessage );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or simply `NSLog(myMessage);`?

Comment: One interesting thing is that the `@` is only required at the start of the first string, but not at each string "component".

Comment: @Macmade: `myMessage` *is* a string literal.

Comment: Is that warning on by default then?  I'm note sure it's got much value as a warning has it?

Comment: @MartinR You're right, obviously... Guess I'm sometimes too paranoid... ^^

Comment: @trojanfoe See comment from MartinR... You can ignore my previous one

Comment: @trojanfoe: The `-Wformat-nonliteral` is not on by default, and it does not have a checkbox in the Compiler Warnings section of the Build Settings tab, so you have to add it "manually" to "Other C flags". It is useful however.